# Control sequences displayed when using git layer

Tags: spacemacs

When I do `SPC g s`, I get something that looks like

```
^[[1mdiff src/main.rs^[[m
```

Pretty much every line has some `^[[` escape sequence.

I'm running inside iterm on mac.  I've tried searching, but I haven't found anyone with the same problem. It seems like its trying to bold the text, but it can't. I don't know if this problem is because of spacemacs or because of iterm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with spacemacs or iterm, but actually with git. For `~/.gitconfig`, under color, change `ui = always` to `ui = auto`.